# What are the odds of each outcome for a round of blackjack?

Tags: probability

I'm trying to model how people lose money at blackjack (considering perfect play).

Let's say the "odds of winning a round of blackjack" are as follows.

- Player wins `43.31%`
- Push `8.80%`
- Dealer wins `47.89%`

Those odds don't take into account the size of the bets won (keep in mind blackjack pays 3:2, and players can split and double when its favorable), so you can't build a good model for blackjack on those figures alone.

What would a better odds table be? Something like this:

- Player wins 1x `34%`
- Player wins 1.5x `3%`
- Player wins 2x (ie successful double or split) `4%`
- Player wins 3x `1%`
- ...
- Player loses 1x `35%`
- ...

...for a relatively standard rule set such as 4 or more decks, no surrender, dealer stands on soft 17.

Comment: First, you have to work out what perfect play is. Then, you'll have some long computation to go through, probably best left to a computer.